# Can i creat a confirmation alert inside the 'foreach' PHP that's used to insert into the database?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two files to extract datas from a XML file using PHP, e Ajax.
There are already working, what i want now is show a confirmation alert inside my foreach where i, in each inserting, ask to the user if he realy wants to make the inserting, by cliking in 'OK' do the inserting and by cliking 'NO' skip to next inserting.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Upload Teste</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#formulario').submit(function(event) {
                var formData = new FormData(this);
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'processaxml.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(result) {
                        $("#idp1").html(result);
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Upload XML</h1>
    <form id="formulario" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="">Arquivo</label>
        <input type="file" name="arquivo" id=""><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="Teste">
        <div>
            <p id="idp1"></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
function forceCarteira($papel, $qtddisp, $total, $precofinal)
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=investimento", "root", "aula");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('insert into investimento.carteira(ticker,nome,qtd,precoacao,precofinal,dataoperacao,
            valorliquido,valorbruto,variacao,precoatual,financeiro,peso) values(:par_ticker,:par_nome,:par_qtd,:par_precoacao,:par_precofinal,
            :par_dataoperacao,:par_valorliquido,:par_valorbruto,:par_variacao, :par_precoatual, :par_financeiro, :par_peso)');

    $dados = array(
        ":par_ticker" => $papel, ":par_nome" => $papel, ":par_qtd" => $qtddisp, ":par_precoacao" => 0,
        ":par_precofinal" => 0, ":par_dataoperacao" => "2020/11/04", ":par_valorliquido" => 0,
        ":par_valorbruto" => 0, ":par_variacao" => 0, ":par_precoatual" => $precofinal, ":par_financeiro" => $total,
        ":par_peso" => 0
    );
    try {
        $stmt->execute($dados);
        echo "Registrado com sucesso <br>";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
if (!empty($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'])) {
    $arquivo = new DOMDocument();
    $arquivo->load($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);
    
    $linhas = $arquivo->getElementsByTagName("Row");

    //laço que faz a inserçao no banco de dados 
    foreach ($linhas as $linha) {
        $papel = $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $qtddisp = $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(8)->nodeValue;
        $precofinal = $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(9)->nodeValue;
        $total = $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(10)->nodeValue;
        if (is_numeric($qtddisp)) {
            //here i want the alert...
            forceCarteira($papel, $qtddisp, $total, $precofinal);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it inside that foreach in PHP. However, you can do it in JavaScript beforehand. When you click on submit, instead of sending the entire FormData, use an async function that loops through the elements of the formData and sends a request to the server for each entry in the formdata. Something like this:

```
        function yourServerRequest(data){
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             $.ajax({
                url:'processaxml.php',
                async: true,
                data: data,
                success:function(result){
                     resolve(result)
                }
            });
          })
        }
        async function sendMyData(formData){ 
         for(var data of formData.entries()) {
          /** Put your code to ask for confirmation here... **/
                if (ok) { //if the user clicked ok
                  var result = await yourServerRequest(data);
                  /** here you can do something after the server answers (the response is 
                   inside result) and before the next cicle **/
                }
         }   
        }
```

Of course you have to adapt your processaxml.php and complete the sendMyData function since it's pseudocode. You could also create a formData for each row instead of packing everything in a formData and have to cicle through it I guess, but the point is that you can do it with async functions.

Comment: what changes do i need to make in my processaxml.php?